# Is there an equivalent to Python's os.remove() on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

Currently I have some code deleting some temporary files created by my program:

```
# Delete the generated files
exts = [".lsys", ".py", ".pyc"]
for ext in exts:
    os.remove("{0}{1}{2}".format(self.grammarDir, filename, ext))
```

Now I'm trying to port the application to Mac. Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove) for Python 2.7, it specifically says:

> Remove (delete) the file path. If path is a directory, OSError is
>   raised; see rmdir() below to remove a directory. This is identical to
>   the unlink() function documented below. On Windows, attempting to
>   remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised; on
>   Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage allocated to the
>   file is not made available until the original file is no longer in
>   use.
>
> ```
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
> ```

Is there an equivalent to `os.remove()` for Mac or am I stuck using something like this?

```
os.system("rm {0}{1}{2}".format(self.grammarDir, filename, ext))
```

I need compatibility with Mac, and maintaining compatibility with Ubuntu would be a huge bonus (but isn't strictly necessary).

**Edit:**

Well, now I feel foolish. Turns out I had a broken call above this segment of code so the deletion code wasn't being reached. Misdiagnosed where my error was, thought it was failing silently.

Comment: Mac OS is an Unix. os.remove should work.

Comment: Modern (OSX) macs are basically unix, so I'd naturally assume it's available under mac as well. Did you try it and it didn't work; or do you mean pre-OSX mac?

Comment: Have you tried this? OS X is based somewhat on Linux.

Comment: Assuming you have to support only Mac OS X, os.remove should work perfectly fine, since Mac OS X is a Unix variant.

Comment: os.remove should be cross-platform.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo, a nit: Mac OS X is definitely not based on Linux! Perhaps you meant to say Unix, as both OS X and Linux are derived from the early Unixes but by different paths.  Under the covers, they are fairly distant cousins.

Comment: @Ned Deily I had a feeling that someone would "nit" on me. I couldn't remember which *Nix it actually was.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Heh. Mac OS X uses a number of things from the BSD family of Unixes but, in many ways, it is also quite different from any of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mac OS X is a Unix, too. From the top of the linked [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html):

> If not separately noted, all functions that claim “Availability: Unix”
>   are supported on Mac OS X, which builds on a Unix core.

Comment: And I completely missed that. Turns out I had a broken call above this segment of code so the deletion code wasn't being reached. Misdiagnosed my error, thought it was failing silently.

Answer (score 5):

Unix in this context means Mac and Linux, too. Problably all [Unix-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)/POSIX-compliant systems that you can build Python on.

Answer (score 4):

`os.remove` is available on Windows and Unix. Max OSX counts as Unix so you can use `os.remove` on Mac OSX.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) that you linked to:

> If not separately noted, all functions that claim “Availability: Unix” are supported on Mac OS X, which builds on a Unix core.